# How to make a count timer C#

Tags: c#, loops, timer, counter

I'm trying to create a timer in c# for an online game.  All i really want is a timer that counts 60 seconds and then restarts. And let it go forever, then add a point for every time it resets...

What i've done so far is:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
int sec = dateTime.Second;

if(sec = 1)
{
    // stuff
}
```

The `if` does not loop, how do I do that? or anyone have a better idea? I'd really like one where i can change the seconds.

Comment: Online game, as in a web based game, or a desktop client that connects to your server?

Comment: After saying `the "if" doesnt loop`, I think you need to go back to the basic, and start with something a bit simpler.

Comment: Did you _expect_ `if` to loop? if yes, could you explain _why_?

Comment: i finaly found something related to what i wanted, posted it as an answere. i do know very well that if doesnt loop, i wrote the question very badly. :P

Answer (score 1):

I think [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) might be useful, just set a callback that triggers after 60 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

i found something related to my question and edited to what i wanted. it does what I want it to do, but does it create overflow or not, that im not sure of. Does anyone have a better idea of doing this?

```
using System;

namespace ticket
{
class Program
{
    public static int x = 0;
    static void LoopingFunction()
    {
        while (x <= 20)
        {
            int dwStartTime = System.Environment.TickCount;

            while (true)
            {

                if (System.Environment.TickCount - dwStartTime > 100) break; //100 milliseconds 

            }
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            x++;
            if (x == 20)
            {
                ///add "stuff"

                Console.WriteLine("Test");
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        LoopingFunction();
        Console.Read();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is going to get the CPU busy all the time, that's why I suggested you to use a timer. May I ask you your level of programming knowledge? Just to help you in the best possible way